# How to print a single row of DataGridView

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, printing, datagridview

Hi guys I've been looking for this help for weeks and didn't get yet the answer
here I go...I have a datagridview , this DGV has a ColumnCheckBox named ("print") and other 3 Columns being (Number,Description,Price)
When I Select a Row by clicking in the ColumnCheckBox("Print")  I want to get the value of the row from this 3 columns mentioned .and by clicking on print button it will print each one of them only the selected row!  guys all my searches runs to create an array and after print from the array but i don't know how !

every answer will be tried and appreciated

Comment: both of them at first is how to get the value from the selected row and set to an array or list , and after how to do a loop on this all got values and print them!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This way you can find a row using some criteria, for example you can find your first checked row:

```
var firstCheckedRow = this.myDataGridView.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
                          .Where(row => (bool?)row.Cells["MyCheckBoxColumn"].Value == true)
                          .FirstOrDefault();
```

This way you can get value of all cells of a row, for example you can put theme together in a string in different lines:

```
var builder = new StringBuilder();
firstCheckedRow.Cells.Cast<DataGridViewCell>()
               .ToList().ForEach(cell =>
               {
                   builder.AppendLine(string.Format("{0}", cell.Value));
               });
```

Then you can for example show them:

MessageBox.Show(builder.ToString());

Or even you can put a `PrintDocument` on your form and handle `PrintPage` event to print them to printer. You also should put a `Button` on form and in click event of button, call `PrintDocument1.Print();`

**Code:**

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PrintDocument1.Print();
}

PrintDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
    var firstCheckedRow = this.myDataGridView.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
                              .Where(row => (bool?)row.Cells["MyCheckBoxColumn"].Value == true)
                              .FirstOrDefault();
    var builder = new StringBuilder();
    firstCheckedRow.Cells.Cast<DataGridViewCell>()
                   .ToList().ForEach(cell =>
                   {
                       builder.AppendLine(string.Format("{0}", cell.Value));
                   });

    e.Graphics.DrawString(builder.ToString(),
               this.myDataGridView.Font,
               new SolidBrush(this.myDataGridView.ForeColor),
               new RectangleF(0, 0, p.DefaultPageSettings.PrintableArea.Width, p.DefaultPageSettings.PrintableArea.Height));
}
```

Comment: Hi Reza Aghaei your code was too usefull to my project! man  thanks!  but i still need to finish  with another criteria!  I will make a new question and tag you there or post the link here! thankx man!

Comment: take a look if the answer were voted!  i noticed that i need to have some reputation score to my vote be public ! i think! by the way do you have some e-mail contact?

Comment: this is my other question Reza Aghaei  printing - how to print only the checked rows from a datagridview in c# - Stack Overflow
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32485741/how-to-print-only-the-checked-rows-from-a-datagridview-in-c-sharp