# how to print only the checked rows from a datagridview in c#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, printing, datagridview

I have a Datagridview it has a checkboxcolumn!
when the data is loaded for standard all rows get checked! but i need to uncheck some of them and them, send it's values to a var and print it!

is it possible?

Exemple:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------
ColumnCheckBox     | Column1      | Column2        | Column3
--------------------------------------------------------------
checked            | 1251000014   | portraitx      | U$ 125.00
checked            | 1251000021   | notebooky      | U$ 899.96
unchecked          | 1265888512   | tabletx        | U$ 899.96  
checked            | 1251444251   | iphoness       | U$ 566.26
unchecked          | 1255222142   | opticalreader  | U$ 99.99
```

I want to get the values of the CHECKED Rows and send to a var and the print it!  the main is ...how to send this values to a var?

thankx in advance!

Comment: hi Reza Aghaei, man I tried so many ways to adapt this code to my project and it was useful partially... I still need to take this value => 1251000014, this value => portraitx,  and this value => U$ 125.00 to three vars and print it  and after the printing clear these 3 vars and take the next checked row values  and do the same! when i select 2 or more rows . the vars is not cleared and so , it print the current  value over the previous one! now when I select 2 or more rows the code sends the values to a single document to print  instead of to each document , being 2 checked rows two documents

Comment: Exactly  Reza Aghaei!  it's what i need  I will try to adapt your code to my project and soon will post the upshot! but that's it each record in a new document

Comment: hey I'm going to success ! and soon i will post the modification!  some adaptations were made in order to separate the builder content in three according to the column quantity equals three! soon I will vote your answer  as helpful... thanks in advance man!

Comment: Done man! you got  successed! thanks for the code!  now I will post the modification!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## **Print all checked rows in a page:**

```
private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
    //Find all checked rows
    var allCheckedRows = this.myDataGridView.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
                                .Where(row => (bool?)row.Cells[0].Value == true)
                                .ToList();

    //create a stringBuilder that will contain the string for all checked rows
    var builder = new StringBuilder();

    //For each checked row, create string presentation of row and add to output stringBuilder
    allCheckedRows.ForEach(row =>
    {
        //Create an array of all cell value of a row to then concatenate them using a separator
        var cellValues = row.Cells.Cast<DataGridViewCell>()
            .Where(cell => cell.ColumnIndex > 0)
            .Select(cell => string.Format("{0}", cell.Value))
            .ToArray();

        //Then joiconcatenate values using ", " as separator, and added to output
        builder.AppendLine(string.Join(", ", cellValues));
        //Here instead of adding them to the stringBuilder, you can add int to another list.      
    });

    //Print the output string
    e.Graphics.DrawString(builder.ToString(),
                this.myDataGridView.Font,
                new SolidBrush(this.myDataGridView.ForeColor),
                new RectangleF(0, 0, this.printDocument1.DefaultPageSettings.PrintableArea.Width, this.printDocument1.DefaultPageSettings.PrintableArea.Height));
}
```

**Output:**

```
1251000014, portraitx, U$ 125.00
1251000021, notebooky, U$ 899.96
1251444251, iphoness, U$ 566.26
```

## **Print each checked row in a separate page:**

```
private int currentPrintingRowIndex = 0;

private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
    var allCheckedRows = this.myDataGridView.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
                                .Where(row => (bool?)row.Cells[0].Value == true)
                                .ToList();

    if (allCheckedRows.Count > currentPrintingRowIndex)
    {
        var builder = new StringBuilder();
        var currentCheckedRow = allCheckedRows[currentPrintingRowIndex];

        var cellValues = currentCheckedRow.Cells.Cast<DataGridViewCell>()
                .Where(cell => cell.ColumnIndex > 0)
                .Select(cell => string.Format("{0}", cell.Value))
                .ToArray();

        builder.AppendLine(string.Join(", ", cellValues));

        e.Graphics.DrawString(builder.ToString(),
                    this.myDataGridView.Font,
                    new SolidBrush(this.myDataGridView.ForeColor),
                    new RectangleF(0, 0, this.printDocument1.DefaultPageSettings.PrintableArea.Width, this.printDocument1.DefaultPageSettings.PrintableArea.Height));

        currentPrintingRowIndex += 1;
        e.HasMorePages = allCheckedRows.Count > currentPrintingRowIndex;
    }
}
```

**Output:**

A document with 3 pages:

```
Page1 content: 1251000014, portraitx, U$ 125.00
Page2 content: 1251000021, notebooky, U$ 899.96
Page3 content: 1251444251, iphoness, U$ 566.26
```

Answer (score 0):

****THIS IS THE FINAL CODE WITH THE HELPFUL CODE ABOVE FROM Reza Aghaei ****

```
           private int currentPrintingRowIndex = 0;

            private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
```

{

```
          Font fsystem = new Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Bold, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
          Font fdatabd = new Font("Arial", 10, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);

          Font fdatabdstrikeout = new Font("Arial", 18, FontStyle.Strikeout, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
          Font fdiag = new Font("Arial", 8, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
          Font fbarra = new Font("C39HrP24DhTt", 30, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
          Font fdesc = new Font("Arial", 8, FontStyle.Bold, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);


           var allCheckedRows = this.dgv1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
                          .Where(row => (bool?)row.Cells[0].Value == true)
                          .ToList();

        if (allCheckedRows.Count > currentPrintingRowIndex)
        {
            var builder = new StringBuilder();


            var currentCheckedRow = allCheckedRows[currentPrintingRowIndex];


            var cellValues = currentCheckedRow.Cells.Cast<DataGridViewCell>()
                    .Where(cell => cell.ColumnIndex > 0)
                    .Select(cell => string.Format("{0}", cell.Value))
                    .ToArray();



            builder.Append(string.Join(",", cellValues));

            //  begin of the aditional implementation

            string ldp = builder.ToString();
            string[] cadaum = ldp.Split(',');

            var cents = cadaum[3].Substring(0, 2);

            var descr = cadaum[1].ToString();

            if (descr.Length >= 30)
            {
                var descr2 = descr.Substring(0, 30);
                var descr3 = descr.Substring(30);

         // end of the aditional implementation

         // begin modification


        //UPPER LEFT SIDE

        e.Graphics.DrawString("TRADEMARK", fsystem, Brushes.Black, 45, 8); 

                e.Graphics.DrawString("COMPANY'S NAME", fdatabd, Brushes.Black, 10, 30);

                e.Graphics.DrawString("ANY OTHER INFORMATION", fdatabd, Brushes.Black, 10, 41);

                e.Graphics.DrawString("made in china", fdatabd, Brushes.Black, 10, 53); 

                if (cadaum[1].Length >= 30)
                {
                    e.Graphics.DrawString(descr2, fdatabd, Brushes.Black, 10, 77);
                }

                e.Graphics.DrawString(descr3, fdatabd, Brushes.Black, 10, 87);

                e.Graphics.DrawString("*" + cadaum[0].ToString() + "*", fbarra, Brushes.Black, 8, 105);


                // UPPER RIGHT SIDE

                 e.Graphics.DrawString("TRADEMARK", fsystem, Brushes.Black, 205, 8);

                 e.Graphics.DrawString("COMPANY'S NAME", fdatabd, Brushes.Black, 170, 30);

                 e.Graphics.DrawString("ANY OTHER INFORMATION", fdatabd, Brushes.Black, 170, 41);

                 e.Graphics.DrawString("made in china", fdatabd, Brushes.Black, 170, 53); 

                 if (cadaum[1].Length >= 30)
                  {
                     e.Graphics.DrawString(descr2, fdatabd, Brushes.Black, 170, 77);                      }

                 e.Graphics.DrawString(descr3, fdatabd, Brushes.Black, 170, 87);

                 e.Graphics.DrawString("*" + cadaum[0].ToString() + "*", fbarra, Brushes.Black, 168, 105);



                // CUTTING REFERENCE


             e.Graphics.DrawString("---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------", fdatabd, Brushes.Black, 1, 147);


                //LOWER LEFT SIDE

                  e.Graphics.DrawString(descr2, fdatabd, Brushes.Black, 10, 155);

                  e.Graphics.DrawString(descr3, fdatabd, Brushes.Black, 10, 165);


                  e.Graphics.DrawString("*" + cadaum[0].ToString() + "*", fbarra, Brushes.Black, 8, 177);

                  e.Graphics.DrawString("Price:", fdatabd, Brushes.Black, 10, 208);



                  e.Graphics.DrawString(cadaum[2].ToString() +"," + cents.ToString(), fdatabd, Brushes.Black, 80, 208);

                  e.Graphics.DrawString("TRADEMARK", fsystem, Brushes.Black, 45, 220); 


                // LOWER RIGHT SIDE


                 e.Graphics.DrawString(descr2, fdatabd, Brushes.Black, 170, 155);

                 e.Graphics.DrawString(descr3, fdatabd, Brushes.Black, 170, 165);


                 e.Graphics.DrawString("*" + cadaum[0].ToString() + "*", fbarra, Brushes.Black, 168, 177);

                 e.Graphics.DrawString("Price:", fdatabd, Brushes.Black, 170, 208);

                 e.Graphics.DrawString(cadaum[2].ToString() + "," + cents.ToString(), fdatabd, Brushes.Black, 240, 208);

                e.Graphics.DrawString("TRADEMARK", fsystem, Brushes.Black, 205, 220);

             // end modification

                currentPrintingRowIndex += 1;
                e.HasMorePages = allCheckedRows.Count > currentPrintingRowIndex;
```