# DataGridView CheckBox - Print checked rows

Tags: c#, winforms, printing, datagridview

I'm beginner in programming.
I created an sql query to fill up a `DataGridView` and I added in the `Column[0]` a `CheckBox` column. I created the checking event. But I don't know how to step forward. I would like to do in

- **First step:** add a check finished button and an event to show only the checked columns.
- **Second step:** all the selected columns rows cell 1 (Name) and cell 2 (ID) to print somehow.
- **Third step:** I want to create a template to print this name and id to an A4 format within  rectangles or some object.

Because I'm new here I need a lot of help!

Thanks in advance!

ps: All step will be a big help for me!

```
private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (string.Compare(dataGridView1.CurrentCell.OwningColumn.Name, "Checked") == 0)
    {
        bool checkBoxStatus = Convert.ToBoolean(dataGridView1.CurrentCell.EditedFormattedValue);

        //"CheckBoxColumn" column value is checked or not. 
        if (checkBoxStatus)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("1");//for check it works or not
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("0");//for check it works or not
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To detect checked rows, when your first column is `DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn` you can use this code:

```
var checkedRows = this.dataGridView1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
                      .Where(row => (bool?)row.Cells[0].Value == true)
                      .ToList();
```

For the rest of problem you can use either of these options:

**Option 1:** Create an [`RDLC Report`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252067.aspx)

If you are using a `DataTable` or a business object as model of your grid, you can simply create an RDLC Report and pass checked rows to the report and print the report.

**Option 2:** Print using [`PrintDocument`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument(v=vs.110).aspx)

To print, use a [`PrintDocument`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument(v=vs.110).aspx) and handle [`PrintPage`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printdocument.printpage(v=vs.110).aspx) event and put the print logic and codes there. To trigger the print event, it's enough to call [`printDocument1.Print()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printdocument.print(v=vs.110).aspx) somewhere in your code.

You can loop over `checkedRows` and use [`e.Graphics.DrawString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.drawstring(v=vs.110).aspx) to print values from each row.

For example:

```
private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
    //Find all checked rows
    var allCheckedRows = this.dataGridView1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
                             .Where(row => (bool?)row.Cells[0].Value == true)
                             .ToList();

    //create a stringBuilder that will contain the string for all checked rows
    var builder = new StringBuilder();

    //For each checked row, create string presentation of row and add to output stringBuilder
    allCheckedRows.ForEach(row =>
    {
        //Create an array of all cell value of a row to then concatenate them using a separator
        var cellValues = row.Cells.Cast<DataGridViewCell>()
                            .Where(cell => cell.ColumnIndex > 0)
                            .Select(cell => string.Format("{0}", cell.Value))
                            .ToArray();

        //Then concatenate values using ", " as separator, and added to output
        builder.AppendLine(string.Join(", ", cellValues));     
    });

    //Print the output string
    e.Graphics.DrawString(builder.ToString(),
                this.myDataGridView.Font,
                new SolidBrush(this.dataGridView1.ForeColor),
                new RectangleF(0, 0, this.printDocument1.DefaultPageSettings.PrintableArea.Width, this.printDocument1.DefaultPageSettings.PrintableArea.Height));
}
```

Comment: Reza Aghaei  Thank you it is very close to what i want!

Comment: Reza Aghaei - can i positioning the rows where they will placed on an A4 size paper? ex.: first row to 10.10 second to 20.10 etc.

Comment: Yes you can apply any logic to drawing, my code is just a sample to print all rows line by line. I added all values to a string and then using `DrawString` redered that string. You can use a for loop over `checkedRows` and call `DrawString` passing suitable text and rectangle.

Comment: Reza Aghaei - I could not success with this. It looks too difficult to me! Can you help me with code to understand how it works?

Comment: When you call `printDocument1.Print()` the `printDocument1_PrintPage` fires and you can put the print logic there. The first thing you should do is finding checked rows. Then when you find the checked rows, you should print each row. For example, you can loop over checkedRows and then print for example value of column[0] of the row. When printing values in the loop, you will use `DrawString` and pass a string and a rectangle or a point to draw string there. When printing the second row you should use new coordinates for your second row, and the second row should be print below the first row.

Comment: So you should use suitable coordinates for each row. In the above example, to make printing simple, instead of printing each row separately, in foreach loop, I concatenate values of columns of a row and put each row in new line in a string and at last I have a multi line string that each line is all values of a row, and I print it.

Comment: Hope this description and comments help you :)

Comment: Also you can check my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32460016/3110834) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32485741/how-to-print-only-the-checked-rows-from-a-datagridview-in-c-sharp/32486166#32486166)

Comment: Reza Aghaei. i checked your comment but i could not solve the first row colum take to an variable and first row sec column to other and 2. row 1.col her second col there...:( etc.

Comment: Dear @Zoltan You don't need to put them in different variables, just draw them when you should draw. for example as a pseudo code: `top=0; foreach row in checkedRows {  draw (row.column[0].value , new point(0,top));  draw (row.column[1].value , new point(100,top));  top +=30;}`  this way, you will draw column 0 at x=0 and y=0 and column 2 at x=100, y=0 and then for next row you will draw at y=30 and next row y=60 and so on.

Comment: @Zoltan If you need more help about this, I think it's better to ask a new question and put the grid and your desired output like this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32485741/3110834) and I surely will help you if I can:)

Comment: Reza Aghaei- Thank you ! You helped me a lot!

Comment: @Zoltan You are welcome, you have got the main idea :)

Comment: @Zoltan Since you have got the main idea and your codes was OK, To keep the answer more general I edited the answer and deleted the chagnes:) By the way, you can vote for answer by click on up arrow near the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

To add a button to DataGridView:

```
DataGridViewButtonColumn editButton = new DataGridViewButtonColumn();
editButton.HeaderText = "Edit";
editButton.Text = "Edit";
editButton.UseColumnTextForButtonValue = true;
editButton.Width = 80;
dbgViewObj.Columns.Add(editButton);
```

**EDIT:**
You could create a new `DataTable` from the previous one and iterate in a for loop to check the state of the checkbox and using the `dgv.Rows.RemoveAt(index)` method to clear the rows that are not checked.Then use `dgv.Columns.Columns.Remove("column_name")` to clear the checkbox column itself.

Comment: Gnqz thank you for your comment it was very usefull! for delete the not checked rows.